# Django Upload/Download File

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to django. In my project I need to add user forms to upload some files and download the uploaded files.

Consider this as an online storage space.
This needs to be handled by class based views so that expansion of the views will be easy.

As of now I tried django-downloadview for objectdownloadview
https://django-downloadview.readthedocs.io/en/1.9/views/object.html
This works quite fine with the example. But I am not able to expand it for class based views for my project.
More over example is with slug I tried changing it to PK but its throwing errors.

I tried below code from django-downloadview example:-

## Views.py

```
from django_downloadview import ObjectDownloadView

from .models import Document


default_file_view = ObjectDownloadView.as_view(model=Document)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Document(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='object')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import  url

from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^object/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$',default_file_view,name='object'),
]
```

Can someone please help me here Or share a working example of simple 1 page django file upload and download stuff.

Regards,
Jaiswal

Comment: Please include in your question the code you have tried and what is the error.

Comment: Added the code of example. This code is working fine but when I am trying to create class based view by inheriting from ObjectDownloadView, I am getting "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error.